# Group databse json objects in an array based on unique id in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a quiz application where student attempts multiple quizes of different weeks and there score are saved in a table called StudentScores. All I want is to retrieve the data (create an API) as such it is grouped by the student Id and all weeks score are summed based on the same Id.
Consider this as my StudentScores table.

```
StID Week Score 
1     1     10
1     3     20
2     1     20
2     2     10
3     1     30
3     3     20
```

This is what I have made so far.

```
      [HttpGet]
        [Route("StudentsScore")]
        public ActionResult GetStudentsScore()
        {
            var courseWeek = db.StudentScores
                
                .Select(c => c.Score).Sum();
                
            return new JsonResult(courseWeek);       
        }
```

Currently it's returning sum of all scores.

```
110
```

I want this API to return this in POSTMAN.

```
[
 {1:30},
 {2:30},
 {3:50}
]
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
 var courseWeek = db.StudentScores.GroupBy(s => s.StID)
            .Select(x => new Dictionary<int,int>()
            {
                {
                    x.Key,
                    x.Sum(i=>i.Score)
                } 
            });
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: can you please explain what x.Key is in this solution.

Comment: After GroupBy,the type is become to IGrouping type,`x.Key` is get the key of IGrouping

Comment: [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=net-5.0).